# Ошибка в коде калькулятора сложного процента

Tags: javascript

Считает максимально ерунду какую-то. Я начинающий, поэтому ошибку не получается выловить. Суть в том, что даже если задать простейшие нач. значения, числа увеличиваются на десятые доли. Например: берем капитал 100, процент 5 и срок 1 год. на выходе: 105.12, хотя должно быть 105. Если использовать нач. значения сложнее, вообще логику результата уловить не могу. Надеюсь на помощь)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var myChart = null;

            function calculate() {
                var principal = parseFloat(document.getElementById('principal').value) || 0;
                var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rate').value) || 0;
                var time = parseFloat(document.getElementById('time').value) || 0;
                var timeType = document.getElementById('timeType').value;
                var monthly = parseFloat(document.getElementById('monthly').value) || 0;
                var inflation = parseFloat(document.getElementById('inflation').value) || 0;

                if (timeType === 'years') {
                    time *= 12;
                }

                rate = rate / 100 / 12; // Convert annual rate to monthly and percentage
                inflation = inflation / 100;

                var total = principal;
                var data = [];
                var labels = [];

                for (var i = 0; i <= time; i++) {
                    if (i !== 0) {
                        total += monthly + (total * rate);
                    }

                    var inflationAdjustedTotal = total / Math.pow(1 + inflation, i / 12);
                    data.push(inflationAdjustedTotal.toFixed(2));
                    labels.push(i);
                }

                var result = data[data.length - 1];
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Итоговая сумма: ' + result;

                updateChart(labels, data);
            }

            function updateChart(labels, data) {
                var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
                var graphType = document.getElementById('graphType').value;

                if (myChart) {
                    myChart.destroy();
                }

                var adjustedData = [];
                var adjustedLabels = [];

                if (graphType === 'years') {
                    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i += 12) {
                        adjustedLabels.push(labels[i] / 12);
                        adjustedData.push(data[i]);
                    }
                } else {
                    adjustedLabels = labels;
                    adjustedData = data;
                }

                myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: adjustedLabels,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'Рост накоплений с учетом инфляции',
                            data: adjustedData,
                            fill: false,
                            borderColor: '#ff845f',
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            pointRadius: 4,
                            pointHoverRadius: 6,
                            pointBackgroundColor: '#ff845f',
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            x: {
                                type: 'linear',
                                title: {
                                    display: true,
                                    text: 'Время (' + (graphType === 'years' ? 'Годы' : 'Месяцы') + ')'
                                }
                            },
                            y: {
                                type: 'linear',
                                title: {
                                    display: true,
                                    text: 'Сумма'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            document.getElementById('calculate-button').addEventListener('click', calculate);
            document.getElementById('graphType').addEventListener('change', calculate);
        });
```

```css
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            max-width: 1200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .calculator, .chart-section {
            flex: 1;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }
        .input-field {
            margin: 10px 0;
        }
        .input-field label {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        .input-field input, .input-field select {
            padding: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .result {
            margin-top: 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .calculate-button {
            background-color: #ff845f;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: none;
        }
        .chart-container {
            max-width: 800px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 400px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="calculator">
            <div class="input-field">
                <label for="principal">Начальный капитал:</label>
                <input type="number" id="principal">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <label for="rate">Процентная ставка (в год):</label>
                <input type="number" id="rate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <label for="time">Срок:</label>
                <input type="number" id="time">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <label for="timeType">Тип срока:</label>
                <select id="timeType">
                    <option value="years">Годы</option>
                    <option value="months">Месяцы</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <label for="monthly">Ежемесячные вложения:</label>
                <input type="number" id="monthly">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <label for="inflation">Среднегодовая инфляция:</label>
                <input type="number" id="inflation" value="0">
            </div>
            <button class="calculate-button" id="calculate-button">Рассчитать</button>
            <div class="result" id="result"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="chart-section">
            <div class="chart-container">
                <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <label for="graphType">Отображение графика:</label>
                <select id="graphType">
                    <option value="months">Месяцы</option>
                    <option value="years">Годы</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Убери из кода все, что не относится напрямую к вопросу

Comment: Почему ты думаешь, что должно быть 105?

Comment: Считается правильно, только периодов у вас не 1, а 12, поскольку у вас в коде период - месяц, а не год. Вы и проценты пересчитываете из годовых в месяц `rate = rate / 100 / 12;`. Поэтому `100*(1+5%/12)**12 = 105,12`

Comment: @АлексейР спасибо!